# Passing parameters with commandButton

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I'm trying to pass a parameter with a `commandButton`. I've seen a few ways to do it on the net, but they don't work. What I have now:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Accept" action="{!acceptDeal}" disabled="{!d.buttonsAreDisabled}">
    <apex:param name="deal" value="{!d.theDeal}" assignTo="{!deal}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

the parameter is not being passed through. Many posts suggest to add `reRender` to my `commandButton`, but when I try that

```
<apex:commandButton value="Accept" action="{!acceptDeal}" disabled="{!d.buttonsAreDisabled}" rerender="someRerenderText">
    <apex:param name="deal" value="{!d.theDeal}" assignTo="{!deal}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

I get the following error:

> Visualforce Error
>
> A String, Number, or Boolean is required for attribute 'value' in <apex:param>.

Another option was to change `commandButton` to `commandLink` with `styleClass="btn"` attribute, but `commandLink` does not have `disabled` attribute that I need.

Comment: It looks like the rerender is helping but just moving you on to the next problem. What exactly are `d.theDeal` and `deal`?

Comment: @KeithC `d` is a variable responsible for table rows. Each table row is an object in apex code which contains a few other objects from salesforce. Table row is an inner class in the controller. `Deal` is a parameter name and there is also a `deal` property in the apex class that represents my custom object `Deal__c`.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message explains, apex:param can only handle primitive values not whole objects. Your description of types isn't entirely clear to me but something like this:

```
<apex:param name="deal" value="{!d.theDeal.Id}" assignTo="{!deal.Id}"/>
```

will work if `d.theDeal` is an SObject and if the `deal` property is pre-populated with a `Deal__c` object. Or you might choose to add a separate `dealId` property to the controller (of type ID):

```
<apex:param name="deal" value="{!d.theDeal.Id}" assignTo="{!dealId}"/>
```

so it is clearer what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. Although I couldn't find the reason why, but it was solved when I just added reRender="". I put nothing inside the quotes. I read on one of the posts that this is a mandate for the param to go through. Although I still don't know why. It worked in my case though. Hope it works for you too.